# GitLab activity from multiple account of the same developer?

Tags: gitlab

I am currently working a project related to work and I use my work account for that project. My overview page on that project is public and can be seen anyone else on the web. On the other hand, I have a private GitLab account that I use for my GitLab activity.

As the GitLab overview page is public and my contributions are visible, can I merge that contributions to my private GitLab overview page?

Answer (score 0):

No, contributions are counted per user account. Emails are unique to each account, meaning each contribution can only be attributed to a single account. There is no functionality to display/merge contributions of two different accounts on one page.

The only workaround would be to use a single account for both your personal and private GitLab activity and [link your work email](https://gitlab.com/-/profile/emails) to your personal account. For example, I simply registered my work emails to my personal gitlab.com account, so my private and public contributions are counted on my profile. Just make sure your personal email is the primary email for the account! Though, this may be difficult if you've already created two different accounts.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these wonderful explanations. Actually linking my work email would let me achieve my goal. But even I tried it on my private GitLab page, it gives "Email has already been taken" error. But in the "Linked emails (2)" section o that page, there is only my private email is listed. SO, what is the problem?

Comment: for testing, I also tried to add my private email to my work GitLab account, but it also gives the same error.

Comment: @harry Unfortunately, emails are uniquely associated with accounts. You _might_ be able to unlink your email from one account then link it with the other, but I'm not sure. Keep in mind that your repositories, memberships, etc, are tied to your _account_ and won't follow your email.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helps, voted up. On the other hand, it is strange that we cannot merge our activities. Because the contributions of a developerX at work may be twice or three times than developerY, but when comparing private GitHub/GitLab account, it is seen that the developerX had no contribution. Am I wrong?

Comment: On the other hand, I think if I update the email on work GitLab, I cannot receive the project files anymore. So, in this scene, it seems to be impossible, but if you have any other suggestion, pls feel free to share with me. Regards.

Comment: Well, if you had originally registered your work email with your personal account, then you wouldn't have this issue. I have done contracting work for many companies and I've used the same GitLab/GitHub accounts for all of them. But it is something you have to think about in advance. Cheers. @harry

Comment: Yes, you right. But I am not sure if I can access to the work projects when I use my private email. So, how do you do that? Getting access permission for your private email from work admin?